# Cannot create a webview inside of a fragment

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin

I've been trying to load a webview inside of a fragment, but none of the methods posted online have worked and causes my app to crash. I have a bottom navigation menu with 5 fragments, and I need each of them to load a different website in webview.

Below is the kotlin file for one  of the fragments:

```
class DaumFrag : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_daum, container, false)
        val mWebView: WebView? = view?.findViewById(R.id.webviewdaum) as WebView
        mWebView?.loadUrl("https://www.daum.net/")

        val webSettings = mWebView?.getSettings()
        webSettings?.setJavaScriptEnabled(true)

        // Force links and redirects to open in the WebView instead of in a browser
        mWebView?.setWebViewClient(WebViewClient())
        return v
    }


}
```

Below is the xml for the fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             tools:context=".DaumFrag">

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="daum"/>
    <WebView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/webviewdaum"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Below is the xml for the mainactivity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" android:orientation="horizontal">

    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/BottomTab"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">
        <WebView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/webview"/>
    </FrameLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation"
            android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
            app:itemTextColor="#000000"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:id="@+id/BottomTab"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginRight="8dp" android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"/>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: It helps if you post your *relevant* section of the crash log, we don't really have any idea what's causing your app to crash.

Comment: try loading web page after view created.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.

You <strike>cannot</strike> should not have two children inside a FrameLayout <strike>(it can only have one)</strike> (it can handle more than one using weights -to avoid overlapping- but this is expensive as it requires multiple measure/layout passes, and also because there are better ways to overlap views or put more than one view in a ViewGroup).

So replace your FrameLayout in your fragment with a `LinearLayout` or better yet, `ConstraintLayout`.

The other problem is this snippet in your activity:

```
   <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/BottomTab"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">
        <WebView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/webview"/>
    </FrameLayout>
```

Remove that webview from there, if that's the fragment container, you're going to put your fragment view in there, so you can't have two children (your fragment AND the webview). Your Fragment XML (above) already has the WebView. You don't need two at the same time.

Additionally, replace all occurrences of `Left` and `Right` with `Start` and `End` respectively to better support RTL languages. E.g. `constraintRight_ToRightOf` should become `constraintEnd_ToEndOf` and so forth.

I'd move all post-creation code to `onViewCreated(...)` though, to ensure your views have been created before you tell them to do things (like load a webpage).

Comment: FrameLayout can hold more than one view but its not preffered. Its hard to organize them.

Comment: I know what FrameLayout can do, but I'm telling you to *not do that* because it's a very bad idea; why would you want to do something the documentation is telling you not to, and I quote: "FrameLayout is designed to block out an area on the screen to display a single item. Generally, FrameLayout should be used to hold a single child view, because it can be difficult to organize child views in a way that's scalable to different screen sizes without the children overlapping each other. You can, however, add multiple children to a FrameLayout ..." this is very inefficient (weights). Don't do it.